# XSLT 1.0: How to combine and sum the fields of children in records based on having the same id field?

Tags: xslt

I have the following:

```
<ns0:tXML>
    <Message>
        <Report>
            <Page>
                <PageID>01</PageID>
                <PageDetail>
                    <PageName>11</PageName>
                    <Totals>
                        <Num>10</Num>
                    </Totals>
                </PageDetail>
                <PageDetail>
                    <PageName>11</PageName>
                    <Totals>
                        <Num>5</Num>
                    </Totals>
                </PageDetail>
            </Page>
            <Page>
                <PageID>02</PageID>
                <PageDetail>
                    <PageName>12</PageName>
                    <Totals>
                        <Num>10</Num>
                    </Totals>
                </PageDetail>
                <PageDetail>
                    <PageName>12</PageName>
                    <Totals>
                        <Num>3</Num>
                    </Totals>
                </PageDetail>
            </Page>
        </Report>
    </Message>
</ns0:tXML>
```

I want to make the output so that PageDetails are combined for each Page as long as their PageName and PageID are the same, including summing the  values of the combined.

Output Wanted:

```
<ns0:tXML>
    <Message>
        <Report>
            <Page>
                <PageID>01</PageID>
                <PageDetail>
                    <PageName>11</PageName>
                    <Totals>
                        <Num>15</Num>
                    </Totals>
                </PageDetail>
            </Page>
            <Page>
                <PageID>02</PageID>
                <PageDetail>
                    <PageName>12</PageName>
                    <Totals>
                        <Num>13</Num>
                    </Totals>
                </PageDetail>
            </Page>
        </Report>
    </Message>
</ns0:tXML>
```

How would I go about it? All efforts with using keys and playing with templates has led to cases where only one of the Pages got created, or it combined all the Pages no matter where they were on the xml, showing that I was likely trying to do an all apply to it rather than sticking to the current context.

Comment: This is a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I went ahead and specificed 1.0. And yeah, I'm aware of grouping, but the normal way of grouping didn't quite work out for me.

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: I deleted it cause I wanted to start fresh. Now that I think about it, I should have saved a copy. It's a bad habit of mines.

Comment: You can start fresh from here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I already did that method. It ended up making it where it summed up all the PageDetail sums, not just one. And it only printed only one PageDetail. When the output got to the second Page to output, it printed the PageName, but ignored making the Totals field cause it already used it in the first output of it.

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from a little correction to your source. It should include
the namespace specification:

```
<ns0:tXML xmlns:ns0="urn.dummy.com">
```

otherwise there is reported the following error:
*The prefix "ns0" for element "ns0:tXML" is not bound*.

One of possible solutions is to use the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="urn.dummy.com">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="Pd" match="PageDetail" use="concat(../PageID, '|', PageName)"/>

  <xsl:template match="Page">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="PageID"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="PageDetail[generate-id()=generate-id(key('Pd',
          concat(../PageID,'|', PageName))[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="kk" select="concat(../PageID,'|', PageName)"/>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="PageName"/>
          <xsl:element name="Totals">
            <xsl:element name="Num">
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('Pd', $kk)/Totals/Num)"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example, generating just your expected result,
see: http://xsltransform.net/93YRmgt

Comment: Why not simply `<Totals>` and `<Num>`, i.e. literal result elements, instead of `<xsl:element name="Totals">` and `<xsl:element name="Num">`? Why do you need to declare the namespace `xmlns:ns0="urn.dummy.com"` in the XSLT although the XSLT doesn't use it?

Comment: Indeed, *xmlns:ns0* in the script is not needed. On the other hand, it is a good practice to "repeat" source namespaces in the script if they were needed. Both *xsl:element* can be replaced with literal elements.